# Comparing prediction distributions across many classes

Tags: probability, neural-networks, correlation, data-visualization, predictive-models

I have a deep neural network with a Softmax classifier as the final layer. For each observation, the network produces a probability distribution over the 64 possible classes that the observation can belong to.

I know that some classes have observations that look very similar and I therefore expect that the probability distributions will show some interesting patterns of which classes the model "finds the most similar".

I would like to use some kind of visualization to show the relationships between the probability distributions across classes. I'm not interested in a confusion matrix as that examines the empirical accuracy. Also, a 64x64 matrix might be difficult to fit nicely in a small figure. Does anyone have a good suggestion for a nice visualization?